# Moving buttons to the bottom of an element

Tags: html, css

I am using Material UI to create cards that take an argument `Actions` which is a list of buttons.

The length of the Card is relative to the text I enter, but all Cards will be the same height.

I am very new to CSS and still wrapping my mind around position: fixed, relative, absolute.

This is the code that renders the Card:

```
export function ViewCurrentPitches2(props) {
    const actions = [
        <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onClick={props.closeEditPitch}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Save"
        primary={true}
        keyboardFocused={true}
        onClick={props.savePitchBeingEdited}
      />,
    ];

    return (
        props.state.savedPitches.map((pitch, i) => {
            return(
                <Card key={pitch.id} className = 'form-margin card-width' zDepth={3}>
                    <CardText>{pitch.subject} </CardText>
                    <CardText className='card'>{pitch.pitch}</CardText>
                    <CardActions>
                        <FlatButton label="Edit" onClick={(e) => {props.toggleEdit(e, pitch); console.log(props.state.pitchBeingEdited)}}/>
                            <Dialog
                                className="dialogBox"
                                title="Test"
                                modal={false}
                                actions={actions}
                                open={props.state.editPitch}
                                contentStyle={customContentStyle}
                                autoScrollBodyContent={true}
                            >
                                <TextFieldExampleCustomize currentValue = {props.state.pitchBeingEdited} updateNewPitch = {props.updatePitchBeingEdited} />
                            </Dialog>

                        <FlatButton label="Delete" onClick={(e) => {props.deletePitch(e, pitch)}} />
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
            )

        })
    )
}

<div className='card-parent'>
    <ViewCurrentPitches2
        state= {this.state}
        deletePitch = {this.deletePitch}
        handleSave={this.dialogBoxSave}
        toggleEdit = {this.toggleEdit}
        closeEditPitch = {this.closeEditPitch}
        updatePitchBeingEdited = {this.updatePitchBeingEdited}
        savePitchBeingEdited = {this.savePitchBeingEdited}
    />
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Can anyone explain to me

1.) When I'm adding in the CSS `position: relative | fixed | absolute` ...etc what is happening? I assign that to the child correct?

2.) If I want to move the buttons to the bottom  of the `Card`, `Card` is the parent and I put the styling on the button? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you would assign `relative` to the parent and `absolute` to the child. The child is being positioned absolutely, relative to the parent.

Refer to [full documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for more details.

```css
.card{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.buttons{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: If I understand this correct, assigning absolute to the parent, essentially "holds it in place" and then the button can be assigned a position relative to the parent?

Comment: I think you have it backwards. You assign `relative` to the parent. The child is then absolutely positioned within the parent.

Comment: ahh ok, I read the wrong documentation. This makes more sense. Thank you.

Comment: There's a natural document flow - if you don't assign anything to anything. However, if for example you assigned absolute to the child but didn't assign relative to the parent then a different DOM element up the tree might act as `relative`. If there are none, it will be the body of your html.

Comment: Honestly, the easiest thing you can do is just fiddle with this snippet. Erase portions of the styles and see what happens. No better way to learn.

Comment: also one other quick quesiton, when I assign a % to a width, what point is it measuring from? ie - from a box https://jsfiddle.net/6qd8f3dk/ the blue box doesn't look centered

Comment: you should start another question for that, we're getting off topic

Comment: btw- thanks for the idea. got it figured out :-) https://jsfiddle.net/6qd8f3dk/1/